# Sort an artists albums by release date with spotify web-api

Tags: spotify

The title kinda describes everything.
I would love to know if its possible to get every data ordered by release date on   https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}/albums
I see that it responds with albums ordered by release date, afterward it responds with singles ordered by release date and so on for album,single,compilation,appears_on.
But I was wondering it was possible to get all of them only ordered by release date. And not in individual groups.
I would prefer to not do any processing after receiving the data.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the [options the API endpoint provides](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/artists/get-artists-albums/), you will have to do some processing on the response

Comment: Yeah i was afraid of that. But ohh well worth a quick ask on here, just in case i was missing something.